# Json data synchronization in database

Tags: php, json

I keep json data from database. I want to sync with the name that comes with the post and get the price of the data I sync. How can I do that?

```php
$video_tkn      = "3D";
$reklam_json    = json_decode($siteayar->reklam_json);
$video          = json_decode($reklam_json->video);

$video_arr      = array();

foreach ($video as $v) {
    if ($v->video_tur==$video_tkn) {
        $video_arr[] = $v->fiyat;
    }else{
        $video_arr[] = 0;
    }
}

print_r($video_arr[0]);

//Output : 0
```

```php
//$reklam_json->video
```

```json
[
   {
      "video_tur":"2D",
      "fiyat":"20"
   },
   {
      "video_tur":"3D",
      "fiyat":"80"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like. The problem with the code that you have written is that in the $video_arr[0] it is always writing 0 as per your else condition because $video_tkn= "3D" value is in second index in the array $video

```
<?php 
$video_tkn      = "3D";
$reklam_json    = json_decode($siteayar->reklam_json);
$video          = json_decode($reklam_json->video);

$video_arr      = array();

foreach ($video as $v) {
    if ($v->video_tur==$video_tkn) {
        $video_arr[] = $v->fiyat;
    }
}

print_r($video_arr[0]);
```